# How to write code which runs upon a Gitlab Job's timeout/fail?

Tags: bash, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Sometimes a job timeouts and gets killed which results in specific resources remaining locked.

Thus the next job fails instantly because it can't access some resources.

Is there a way tell GitLab to run a script upon timeout/fail? (which would unlock all "possibly locked" resources)

Comment: I don't think it'd be a good idea to "run a script upon timeout/fail", but to rather find the error. From what it sounds like, it most probably is a server side **permission error**. Try running your project in debug mode `yourproject --debug run`. Or just look up the files which can't be accessed and check their permissions.

Comment: No, not a permission error. An app locks that "repository", starts processing it, and then due to timeout the job is killed. Thus the process never finishes and the "repository" remains locked. (The app would unlock it after it's finished). The next job says instantly that the "repository" is locked. So I have to manually send an unlock command and restart the job. I hope I made it clear :\

Comment: I think I understand your problem. But: Why does the job timeout? - due to a permission error? Wouldn't it be cleaner, to solve what causes the job to timeout, instead of a workaround to unlock the resource upon fail?

Comment: Yes, it would be. It's a backup job and sometimes it just takes too much time due to currently unknown reasons. I wrote this issue in the document nearby but still if I'm not working that day I think there's nobody to fix it. So I guess it would be safer to have an automatic way to make it fixed. Like when I cancel the operation manually, the app unlock the resources. But killing the job just pulls the plug instantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the documentation (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#when) , you could create a seperate job in the next stage that uses `when: on_failure` to clean up resources.

```
cleanup_build_job:
  stage: cleanup_build
  script:
    - cleanup build when failed
  when: on_failure
```

For this to work, of course your previous job would need to fail. You can manually define timeouts per job as for example:

```
build:
  script: build.sh
  timeout: 10 minutes
```

The `on_failure` job is executed when at least one job in an earlier stage fails, so if you have multiple jobs before, you might need to use additional variables   to validate if the cleanup should be run.